# Linearization of a function in 1D

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, linearization

I sincerely hope you can provide me with some help. I am currently studying for my advanced Calculus and I got stuck on this question.

The question in regard is: Calculate the linearizations of φ and ψ around 2.

With the functions being given by,
$φ(x)^2$ + $sin(φ(x)ψ(x))$ = 2 − x,
and
$φ(x) + ψ(x)$ = $x^2$

**What I tried**
Well, what I have tried to do was to create both functions where the right-hand side would be zero and then differentiate them both with respect to x from this you get a system of equations and then just solve them for both.

I see that I have to use the chain rule ( and product rule for sin(phi) to get them but when I differentiate $φ(x)^2$  I get$ 2φ(x)_x$ whereas the answer gives me 2φ(x) I have not tried differentiating $sin(φ(x)ψ(x))$ yet but I expect it to become something like $φ_x(x)ψ(x)cos(φ(x)ψ(x))$+$φ(x)ψ_x(x)cos(φ(x)ψ(x))$

If somebody could help me it would be greatly appreciated.
Picture attached with answers from the professor.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fovGC.png)

Answer (score 1):

You want to write both functions as

$$\phi(x) \approx \phi(2) + \phi'(2) \, (x-2)$$

$$\psi(x) \approx \psi(2) + \psi'(2) \, (x-2)$$

So you need to calculate $\phi(2)$, $\psi(2)$, $\phi'(2)$ and $\psi'(2)$.

$$$$

(a) $\phi(2)$ and $\psi(2)$

$$\begin{matrix}
\phi^2(x) + \sin(\,\phi(x)\,\psi(x)\,) = 2 − x & \rightarrow & \phi^2(2) + \sin(\,\phi(2)\,\psi(2)\,) = 0\\
\phi(x) + \psi(x) = x^2                           & \rightarrow & \phi(2) + \psi(2) = 4
\end{matrix}$$

This system is transcendental and may have more than one solution. But $\phi(2) = 0$ and $\psi(2) = 4$ is clearly one of them.

$$$$

(b) $\phi'(2)$ and $\psi'(2)$

Differentiate each side of both equations to get:

$$\begin{matrix}
2\,\phi(x)\,\phi'(x) + \cos(\,\phi(x)\,\psi(x)\,) \,  [\,\phi'(x)\,\psi(x)+\phi(x)\,\psi'(x)\,] = -1 & \rightarrow & 2\,\phi(2)\,\phi'(2) + \cos(\,\phi(2)\,\psi(2)\,) \,  [\,\phi'(2)\,\psi(2)+\phi(2)\,\psi'(2)\,] = -1\\
\phi'(x) + \psi'(x) = 2x                           & \rightarrow & \phi'(2) + \psi'(2) = 4
\end{matrix}$$

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
2\,\phi(2) + \cos(\,\phi(2)\,\psi(2)\,) \, \psi(2) & \cos(\,\phi(2)\,\psi(2)\,) \, \phi(2)\\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
\phi'(2)\\
\psi'(2)
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
-1\\
4
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

For $\phi(2) = 0$ and $\psi(2) = 4$, we get:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
4 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
\phi'(2)\\
\psi'(2)
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
-1\\
4
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

And finally, $\phi'(2) = -1/4$ and $\psi'(2) = 17/4$.